# osm file, parsing, memory error even with clearing elements.

Tags: python, json, memory, openstreetmap

I want to take an osm file, clean it, and then save it as a json file.
The xml file is about 1 gb big.

```
def audit():
    osm_file = open('c:\Users\Stephan\Downloads\los-angeles_california.osm', "r")
    with open('lala.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for event, elem in ET.iterparse(osm_file, events=("start",)):   
            if elem.tag == "node" or elem.tag == "way":
                json.dump(shape_element(elem),outfile)
                elem.clear()  
audit()
```

Eventhough i use elm.clear() i still get an memory error. Anyone knows why ?

Comment: Maybe there's lots of elements, even though you clear them, the empty element remains. Also it would help if you provided a complete example with a data file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
osm_file = open('c:\Users\Stephan\Downloads\los-angeles_california.osm', "wr")
```

if you want to clean it, it should be writable

Comment: That doesn't make any sense if he wants to read a XML file and write a JSON file. But his question is not very clear.

Comment: "elem" is taken from "osm_file" file and "elem.clear()" is to clear from the "osm_file" file all the elem's subelements so this file has to be writable isnt it?

Comment: I'm just saying that his question sounds like he want to write a cleaned up JSON file without modifying the original file.